# Windows 10 Professional on QEMU

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I am running a host with a AMD 4 core processor. I tried to allocate 3 cores to my Windows VM but it only sees or recognizes 2 per System Monitor. Has anyone been able to get Windows 10 to utilize more than 2 cores? Even on different virtualization? Specs/config please. Could it have something to do with my host having 4 cores?

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: See if this helps - https://serverfault.com/questions/101434/why-does-my-windows-7-vm-running-under-linux-kvm-not-use-all-the-virtual-proces

Comment: I see this as being a Windows problem. Not of Ubuntu.

Comment: @Rinzwind - for the most part, however, there may be configuration options  in QEMU / KVM that may help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed the same type of problem with my Win10 VM - I modified the topology for the guest as shown in the image below, and now my system monitor shows 3 virtual processors.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

desktop Windows versions (Windows 11/10/8.1/7) have a restriction on the maximum number of physical processors (sockets) a computer can use:

- Windows Home – 1 CPU
- Windows Professional – 2 CPU
- Windows Workstation – up to 4 CPU
- Windows Server – up to 64 CPU

However, this restriction is not related to the number of cores.

In order to improve the performance of your virtual machine, you can use a processor with more cores. Most hypervisors can provide vCPUs as processors, processor cores or even threads. It means that instead of 8 vCPUs, you can add 2 vCPUs (2 sockets) with 4 per socket.

**In KVM Hypervisor running Windows 10 VM, all assigned virtual cores are considered as separate processors. To use all CPU resources allocated to a Virtual Machine, it must see one 8 core processor (or 2 in Professional).**

KVM hypervisor allows the user to set the number of virtual cores used by each virtual machine.

example config:

```
<cpu mode='host-passthrough' check='none'>
<topology sockets='1' cores='8' threads='1'/>
</cpu>
```